# Highlight Headings in Navigation Pane in Word for Mac that contain the search string

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word

In the Windows version of Microsoft Word, I find it VERY useful that the headings listed in the Navigation pane get highlighted if their contents contain the search string. In this way, I can manually zero in on the search results only for sections I deem applicable. I feel severely handicapped when I switch to the Mac version of Word that it only highlights one heading at a time.

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality in the Mac version of Word?

Comment: I think the only thing you might try is Office Color Schemes (under Office Account in an Office App). If not that, then I do not know another way.

Comment: Send feedback to Word developers. https://support.microsoft.com/office/2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11 Word for the Mac and Word for Windows are different programs. The Navigation Pane in the two versions is quite different. The miracle is that they are as compatible as they are.